# Como chamar uma função PHP que retorna uma string usando jQuery ou JavaScript?

Tags: php, html, jquery

Eu tenho um arquivo PHP que retorna a quantidade de usuário cadastrados em um banco de dados MySQL. Eu queria saber se há uma maneira de colocar esse número dentro de uma div usando jQuery ou JavaScript sem precisar colocar PHP dentro do HTML.

**getinfo.php**

```php
<?php
function getaccounttotal() {
    try
    {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8', '', '');
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `database`.`accouunts`;");
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchColumn();

        // The script will automatically free the result and close the MySQL
        // connection when it exits, but let's just do it anyways
        $dbh = null;

        return $result;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/loginStyle.css">
    <script src="js/lib/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Usuários cadastrados<p id="accountnumber"></p></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: com ajax, ai você manipula o DOM de acordo com o retorno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar o método `.load()` do jQuery:

```
$(seletor).load(url);
```

Onde:

- **Seletor:** elemento para onde o resultado da requisição será enviado.
- **url:** página a ser requisitada.

No seu caso ficaria:

```
$("#accountnumber").load("getinfo.php");
```

E no PHP você faz um `echo` da função:

```
<?
function getaccounttotal(){
   // código
}

echo getaccounttotal(); // envia o retorno da função para o AJAX
?>
```